# I want to export the eigenvalues of the large matrix as .dat file

Tags: export, data

I want to know the eigenvalues of below matrix $H(k)=$

[image]

Now, $To$ and $M$ are constants and $T1$ and $T2$ are functions as k.

$T1=2t_1\cos{\frac{k}{2}}$

$T2=2t_2\cos{\frac{k}{2}}$

$t1$ and $t2$ are constants. I want to know the eigenvalues of matrix H(k) each k numerically. And I want to plot the eigenvalues of H(k) as the function of k. So I wrote

```
n=15;
For[k = 0, k < 2 Pi, k = k + 0.01,
M = 0.01;
To = 1.86;
T1 = 2*0.63*Cos[k/2];
T2 = 2*0.35*Cos[k/2];
H = Table[If[i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}]+
Table[If[i==j && (Mod[i,4]==1||Mod[i,4]==2),M,0],{i,n},{j,n}]+
Table[If[i==j && (Mod[i,4]==3||Mod[i,4]==0),-M,0],{i,n},{j,n}]+
Table[If[i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, To, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, To, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i == j + 3 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T2, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i + 3 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T2, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}];
For[q = 1, q < n, q++, Print[{k, Eigenvalues[N[H]][[q]]}]]
]
```

Now, I can get eigenvalues of H each k numerically. But I need data of {k,eigenvalues of H} to plot the eigenvalues as function of k. How should I export?

I am a beginner of Mathematica. I use Mathematica 8.

Comment: Is there a reason you're getting a list of matrices for different values of `k` rather than just defining `H[k]` and getting the eigenvalues of that (which would also be functions of `k`). Then you could just plot them with something like `Plot[evals[k], {k, 0, 2π}]`... or do have have to export as a .dat file in order to use it with other software?

Comment: Yes, I want to use gnuplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

First, there are nicer ways to specify your matrix. You can define it as a function of `k` by constructing the diagonals and then summing:

```
M = 0.01;
To = 1.86;
T1 = 2*0.63*Cos[k/2];
T2 = 2*0.35*Cos[k/2];

H[k_] = DiagonalMatrix[{M, M, -M, -M, M, M, -M, -M, M, M, -M, -M, M, M, -M}] +
   DiagonalMatrix[Riffle[Table[T1, 7], To, {2, -1, 2}], -1] +
   DiagonalMatrix[Riffle[Table[T1, 7], To, {2, -1, 2}], 1] +
   DiagonalMatrix[Riffle[Table[T2, 6], 0, {1, -2, 2}], -3] +
   DiagonalMatrix[Riffle[Table[T2, 6], 0, {1, -2, 2}], 3];
```

Note the use of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`) rather than [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (':=').

Then

```
evals[k_] = Eigenvalues[H[k]];
```

gives you a list of the `n` eigenvalues as functions of `k`. Then you can plot them with

```
Plot[Evaluate@evals[k], {k, 0, 2 π}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The middle of the plot is blank because the eigenvalues are complex around `k = π`. You could also plot `Re@evals[k]` and `Im@evals[k]` to get the real and imaginary parts, if you wanted.

Now you can easily create some data:

```
data = Table[{k, evals[k]}, {k, 0, 2 π, 0.01}];
```

and export it with

```
data >> "evals.dat"
```

which just puts the list into the file "evals.dat".

The entries in data have the form, e.g.:

```
data[[1]]

(* {0., {-3.68394, -3.296, -2.7139, -2.02278, -1.32672, -0.720975,
    -0.28961, 0.000106055, 0.291254, 0.722742, 1.32807, 2.02637, 
    2.71489, 3.29644, 3.68406}} *)
```

where the first element is the value of `k` and the second is a list of the eigenvalues for that `k`. If you want it in a different form (I don't know how Gnuplot likes its data), you can play about with the `Table` I used to make it.

Hope that helps.